# How can I have 2 files of the same name in an eclipse project but in 2 different sub-folders?

Tags: java, eclipse, subdirectory

Right now I have a set up like this:

...\lab18\18a\18a.java

...\lab18\18a\monster.java

and

...\lab18\18b\18b.java

...\lab18\18b\monster.java

the issue is the 2 'monster.java' files in the 18a and 18b sub-folders, is there a way to keep these names the same but not cause errors on the 'monster.java' in the 18b, 18c, etc sub-folders? The error eclipse is stating is that `Monster` is already defined referencing to the .java file in the 18a folder.

here is a screenshot of what I'm referring to:
[image: screenshot of question]

Here is a screenshot of how the files and folders are organized in Windows explorer: [image: Windows Explorer screenshot]

Comment: Just so I understand: You want to references both "monster" classes in the same java file?

Comment: I want to reference the "monster.java" file located in the 18a folder with just the "18a.java" file and the "monster.java" file in the 18b folder with only the "18b.java" file. Hope that clears it up...

Comment: Does reference mean you want to import them?

Comment: see if the screenshot I uploaded helps out with what I'm trying to ask. and reference is not meaning import, it's just how I mentally view the files in each folder accessing each other

Comment: why two default packages? if you have packages like lab18b you don't need the default packages... that's just for classes without package declaration.

Comment: @FranzEbner that's how the files were when I obtained them and for all I can tell, it's best they stay that way and it created individual default packages for each sub-folder when I created a new project using the file `lab18...`

Comment: as far as packages are concerned, I leave them as default packages when eclipse creates them, otherwise it's beyond my knowledge as far as how to properly set that sort of stuff up

Comment: you can't have two classes with the same name (Monster.java) in one package

Comment: Whatever you do, it doesn't make to have two classes of the same name in the same package in the same project. Any one of those three "sames" has to go.

Comment: does Eclipse view a `default package` as a single package even if there's one in each source folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same source folder, two packages:

[image]

---

Package declaration in the Java classes
[image]

-> Same project, same source folder, different packages, same class name.

Comment: each 18 folder (ie 18a, 18b) is already it's own source folder I believe so if each 18 folder has a package, even though it's default, should cause no problems, right? And is your answer implying that the content in each `Monster.java` file is different?

Comment: there should only be one src folder per project, several packages per source folder, and several classes per package. If you don't need different Monser Classes, only make one and place it a level up in the package tree. Than import the class in every Lab18 class.

Comment: I do need different Monster classes however

Comment: No problem if they are named different or even better in this case, placed in different packages as showed above.

Comment: How should anyone know, which class you mean, if you name all the same and put them into the same package...?

Comment: so if I were to use different packages, that would mean creating a new package in each "18 folder" in order to retain the original names, right? And logically, I agree with your comment about naming them the same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24795/discussion-between-franz-ebner-and-tech-geek23)

Answer (score 0):

You have put them into the same package (default package) within two different source folders. The only way  you will be able to have two classes with the same name is if they are in different packages.

For example,  for lab18 one, put it into a subfolder called lab 18a and put lab18b into a subfolder called lab18b

```
lab18_oop_interfaces
  lab18a
    lab18a
      Lab18a.java
      Monster.java
  lab18b
    lab18b
      Lab18b.java
      Monster.java
```

Alternatively, put both the subfolders into one src folder and mark that as the source folder:

```
lab18_oop_interfaces
  src
    lab18a
      Lab18a.java
      Monster.java
    lab18b
      Lab18b.java
      Monster.java
```

Comment: automatically when I created the java project in eclipse using the lab18_oop_interfaces folder eclipse made default packages each for 18a, 18b, 18c, etc.

Comment: Right click on the file, Refactor -> Move (I think ) and you can choose another package (i.e. lab18a / lab18b)